# How to deploy django app on hosting service

Tags: python, django, deployment, web-hosting

I'm new to web development. I bought the web hosting start-up package from Siteground to host my graphic design portfolio website. It's a simple Django app that is a one-page portfolio with a contact form using Django's sendEmail through gmail service.

I've never deployed a Django app, let alone my own website. I've only made and deployed a Wordpress website which is pretty self-explanatory.

I understand how to upload my website to the server through FTP, but I have no idea how to configure the Django app for deployment (aside the brief explanation in their docs) or how to connect the app to my server to run on the domain.

I think I'm supposed to configure something in wsgi, but I don't really understand how that works and I can't find support anywhere on deploying a Django app on Siteground (or something like it) even though they have python support.

I connected to Sitegrounds' SSH to follow some tutorials on Django deployment, but even though it's Linux I can't use (or don't understand how to) sudo apt-get to follow the tutorials.

Here is my settings.py:

```
import os

with open('cfsite/key.txt') as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.read().strip()

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Debug Settings
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'cfapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cfsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cfsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/iamcrys8/public_html/static'

# Crispy Forms settings

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'


# Email Backend settings

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '(email go here)'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '(email pass go here)'
```

I know I have to change 'Debug=True' to 'Debug=False' and insert my domains' IP in the 'Allowed_Hosts' as well as pointing my directories to the servers' directory (public_html), but that's all I know.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to understanding how to deploy python apps on Siteground? Or at least point me to a resource that explains the deployment of python apps on server hosting services?

Is it possible to keep sqlite or do I have to learn mysql (which Siteground has support for)?

Edit: Here is Sitegrounds' deployment information regarding non-Wordpress or Joomla websites (which they have barely any information on).

> 1. Move your files: First, you will need to move your website files from your previous host to SiteGround by using FTP (File Transfer
>      Protocol).
> 2. Move your database: Then, you will have to move your database. Start with exporting the database from your previous hosting account.
>      If you’re not sure how to do this, contact the support of your
>      previous host to get more info. When you get your data exported,
>      create a new database on your new SiteGround hosting account and
>      import your content into it.
> 3. Reconfigure your application: The last step of transferring your site is to reconfigure your application to work from the new place. In
>      WordPress, that's the wp-config.php file, while in Joomla it is
>      configuration.php. Replace the values with your actual database,
>      database username and password for it. Save this file and your site
>      should be up and running from your new SiteGround hosting account. The
>      configuration steps for every application are different.

The only other info regarding deployment is specific to Wordpress or other PHP frameworks.

Comment: Which Unix flavour is it?

Comment: Can we also see their deployment information?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser Ahh, my mistake it is Linux CentOS according to their support page. I'm not really familiar with either of the two (unix or linux, aside from basic Terminal navigation).

Comment: @MatthewGaiser I also edited OP with their notes on transferring websites to their server... I cannot find anything regarding deployment specifically except by using their 'SG-Git' tool for cloning repos to your domain or staging your projects (which only shows for Wordpress and other PHP frameworks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone please point me in the right direction to understanding how
>   to deploy python apps on Siteground? Or at least point me to a
>   resource that explains the deployment of python apps on server hosting
>   services?

I just deployed a Django app to production on CentOS a few weeks ago. SSH tells me that you would be using a virtual machine of some sort, so these tutorials should be perfect for you:

https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-django-on-centos-7

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7

I used these. We were using the same stack as the DigitalOcean one.

> Is it possible to keep sqlite or do I have to learn mysql (which
>   Siteground has support for)?

You can continue to use SQLite. I am not sure what additional configuration it would require.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, hopefully, this will get me where I need to be or at least in the right direction!

Comment: @EthanThompson Did you ever get this working on Siteground?

Comment: @Dfarrelly I did not, I migrated my site over to DigitalOcean, which is significantly easier to configure.

Comment: I have actually done the same already, after talking with siteground support, they confirmed it wasn't possible, so I switched to DigitalOcean also.

Comment: I chatted with siteground team today, they say I could run python modules like Django with their growbig plan. ? I am still confused if that will work or not.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil I don't know if they have added this capability recently, but the last time I checked they still were unable to host python apps. Which is crazy because Python web apps are like the most popular ones right now...

Answer (score 0):

They actually have a `Python` interpreter installed, but just supply the standard packages. It's not possible to install new ones via `pip`. Compare https://www.siteground.com/kb/see-available-python-modules/

I also asked their support.